# Is there a function in R that both bind_rows() and bind_cols()?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that I would like to get sum of each row and frequency for each column. I have tried to use table and summary but I did not get the right result.

Here is the sample dataset:

```
      A B C D E
      0 1 0 1 0
      1 0 0 1 1
      1 0 0 0 1
      1 1 1 0 0
      0 1 1 0 1
      1 1 0 1 0
      1 0 0 0 0
```

The expect output:

```
         A B C D E Sum
         0 1 0 1 0  2
         1 0 0 1 1  3
         1 0 0 0 1  2
         1 1 1 0 0  3
         0 1 1 0 1  3
         1 1 0 1 0  3
         1 0 0 0 0  1
 freq(1) 5 4 2 3 3
 freq(0) 2 3 5 4 4
```

How can I do it? Thank you!

Comment: You may use `addmargins` i.e. `addmargins(as.matrix(df1))` would be close to what you want

Comment: Hi Akrun, when I applied addmargins,  it gave me this message. Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument Then I tried to unlist, and got this Error in FUN[[i]] : subscript out of bounds

Comment: It needs a `matrix` as in Ian's post

Comment: Many thanks :) @akrun

Comment: I will do next time. Both are great. Thank you:)

Comment: @akrun was trying to help me by giving comment and you were faster to put the answer. Thanks for you guys help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @akrun noted while I was formatting the output, `addmargins` from base R is one option:

```
addmargins(as.matrix(data))
    A B C D E Sum
    0 1 0 1 0   2
    1 0 0 1 1   3
    1 0 0 0 1   2
    1 1 1 0 0   3
    0 1 1 0 1   3
    1 1 0 1 0   3
    1 0 0 0 0   1
Sum 5 4 2 3 3  17
```

Comment: @lan Campbell, thanks. It works. But I could not get whole result.  [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 2 rows ] because the table has too many row. How can I get the sum rows?

Comment: @almo, that's just because the output was truncated in your terminal. Assign it to a new object and view `head` and `tail` as required.

Comment: How do you expect the output? If you don't need this type of output, you could just use `colSums(data)` and `rowSums(data)`.

Comment: Or, `margin.table(as.matrix(data), 1)` for rows and `margin.table(as.matrix(data), 2)` for columns.

Comment: @IanCampbell I will use the result to generate a new dataframe. That's why

Comment: Thanks @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1, you name is a little bit long though :D

Comment: Another option would be `library(janitor); library(tibble);rownames_to_column(df1, 'rn') %>% adorn_totals(c('row', 'col'))`

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the `addmargins` in @Ian Campbell's, another option is `adorn_totals`

```
library(dplyr)
library(janitor)
library(tibble)
rownames_to_column(df1, 'rn') %>% 
       adorn_totals(c('row', 'col')) %>% 
       add_row(rn = 'Total_Zero', !!! colSums(df1 == 0))
```

-output

```
#         rn A B C D E Total
#          1 0 1 0 1 0     2
#          2 1 0 0 1 1     3
#          3 1 0 0 0 1     2
#          4 1 1 1 0 0     3
#          5 0 1 1 0 1     3
#          6 1 1 0 1 0     3
#          7 1 0 0 0 0     1
#      Total 5 4 2 3 3    17
# Total_Zero 2 3 5 4 4    NA
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), B = c(1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), C = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), D = c(1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), E = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L)),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: Many appreciate@akrun :)

Comment: @almo Glad to help you.  Thanks